# How to deploy React App on Github Pages (only background color is seen)

Tags: reactjs, deployment, hosting, github-pages, npm-scripts

Currently am trying to deploy my React Project on Github Pages, however I am unable to do so. After publishing on gh pages, all I am getting is a screen with the correct background color, but without any of the content.

I used these 2 pages to try and figure out how I could deploy my page and they are https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-github-pages/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9n2mLqXFpU&ab_channel=PedroTech.

Also after doing npm run deploy I am now running into some issues when I run npm start. I am instead automatically taken to the page localhost:3000/space-tourism-website, but to get to my page it is on localhost:3000/

Source code is on github: https://github.com/farhan-navas/space-tourism-website. If any more info is needed please do let me know. Would be very thankful for any tips and help.

```
"name": "space-tourism-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://farhan-navas.github.io/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

this is how the top section package.json file looks like. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming your repository to `farhan-navas.github.io`

Comment: hey man thanks this somewhat worked! Unfortunately, still have a few issues, i wrote some code in react to extract pictures from a json file according to a specific file path, and none of these pictures were displayed on my page and i get a 404 GET error. Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: Hmm that’s weird, are you using vercel to host the site?

Comment: After clicking this link: https://space-tourism-website-farhan-navas.vercel.app/home it seems to be working fine

Comment: Yep my bad bro i just figured that I would deploy on vercel because this was taking a lot of time and I couldn't figure it out so sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep! only issue is that now the browser seems to be abit zoomed in on my pages while in desktop mode so imma go see what I can do to fix it, will try to uninstall all the gh pages dependencies first

Answer (score 0):

Not really answered, but I have decided to deploy my project on vercel instead of github-pages and would recommend the same to anyone else who is trying to deploy a react project on github pages!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).